# Cordova App, Facebook Api integration : Unable to fetch email , date of birth and other details except Id and name

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

I am new to cordova and I am developing a cordova app with facebook login integration.
 I am using the `facebookConnectPlugin`.
 
I can login successfully but unable to get the email and other data except id and name.. 
I used  the following to login

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["public_profile"], 
                             function(data){
                                 console.log(data);
                                 console.log('login success');
                             }, 
                             function(e){                   
                                 console.log(e);                    
                             });
```

and tried to get the email using

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api( "me/?fields=id,email&debug=all",
                           ["public_profile"], 
                           function(data){
                               console.log(data)
                           },
                           function(y){
                               console.log(y);
                           });
```

but It not returning email but returns id..

also some times returns

> Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

Can anyone help me in sorting out the issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: The user first need to grant email permission to your app

Comment: @WizKid : How should I enable this to the app for testing? May I have to login to my facebook account or developer.facebook ... I lack the knownledge of facebook workings since I doesn't used facebook much.

Comment: You can ask anyone that has a role on the app for any permission